# How do I achieve this camera lines effect in photoshop or Ai

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

If you zoom in this image, there are parallel lines throughout which are used to show a cctv like effect.
Tried with various blending options, but in vain. How do I achieve this ?

Comment: http://photoshopcafe.com/tutorials/scanlines/scan.html

Comment: Did you try searching for how to do this? It's a very popular effect, "[tv lines photoshop](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=tv%20lines%20photoshop)" returns lots of results (including joojaa's)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a **New Document** that is 1 pixel by 2 pixels....

[image]

Zoom in and color the **top pixel black**....

[image]

Choose `Select > Select All` from the menu.

Then choose `Edit > Define Pattern` from the menu and save the pattern. You can then close the new document and there's no need to save it. It is merely used to create the pattern.

Now, go back to your original image and add a **Pattern Overlay Layer Style** to any layer you wish to have the lines on....

[image]

You can then adjust the blending mode or opacity to your liking.

There are *literally* thousands of tutorials online for this if you merely search for "scan lines Photoshop tutorial".

For **illustrator** it's pretty much the same idea.. overlay a pattern of horizontal lines. Illustrator does ship with some default line patterns though `Patterns > Basic Graphic Pattern > Basic Graphic Lines` from the **Swatch Panel**. So, there's no need to create your own pattern.